# Chrome Devtool: brown dashed lines

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I open the Chrome devtools my website is displaying weird brown dashed lines:
[image]

Is it a setting that I should disable or something ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've previously clicked `flex` in the element inspector tree:

[image]

Click it again to toggle.